# Wagmi throws Error ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "owner" returned no data ("0x")

Tags: wagmi

I'm using Wagmi (v1.3.9) and viem (v1.3.0) with Next 13 (v13.4.12) using the app directory. I have a WagmiProvider wrapper wrapped around children in the layout.tsx file. I've also copy/pasted the abi array from hardhat artifacts which includes the owner function. Here's the constructor for my contract which also uses VRF from chainlink (although I don't think that would affect what I'm trying to fix):

```
 constructor(
   uint256 _entryCost,
   uint64 subscriptionId
 ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(0x...) {
   COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(
     0x...
   );
   owner = msg.sender;
   entryCost = _entryCost;
   s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
}
```

I've deployed my contract on Sepolia and use either the read contract within Etherscan or Remix to verify that there is an owner function that displays the address of the deployer.

Within my Navbar component, I have the following code:

```
"use client";

import { Container, Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { RAFFLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, TOKENRAFFLE_CONTRACT_ABI } from "../../../const/";
import { Web3Button } from "@web3modal/react";
import { useAccount, useContractRead } from "wagmi";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const { address, isConnecting, isDisconnected } = useAccount();

  const {
    data: ownerAddress,
    isError,
    isLoading,
  } = useContractRead({
    address: RAFFLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    abi: TOKENRAFFLE_CONTRACT_ABI,
    functionName: "owner",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return <></>;

  return (
    <Container
      maxW={"1440px"}
      py={8}
    >
      <Flex
        flexDirection={"row"}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
        alignItems={"center"}
      >
        <Link href={"/"}>
          <Text>RAFFLE APP</Text>
        </Link>
        <Flex
          flexDirection={"row"}
          alignItems={"center"}
        >
          {!isLoading && ownerAddress == address && (
            <Link href={"/admin"}>
              <Text mr={4}>Admin</Text>
            </Link>
          )}
          <Web3Button />
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I'm expecting that whenever the Navbar component is rendered, the owner address should be returned.

Instead I'm getting the following error message within my browser console:

app-index.js:31 ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "owner" returned no data ("0x").

This could be due to any of the following:

- The contract does not have the function "owner",
- The parameters passed to the contract function may be invalid, or
- The address is not a contract.

I've also tried hard-coding in an address of another contract I've made into the aforementioned useContractRead and it returns the contract owner address.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this challenge, it's very easy to fix, what is happening here is that Wagmi is reading your contract on the wrong blockchain probably `mainnet`.
To fix this you have to configure Wagmi to read from your chain just add sepolia to the array as shown below.
This code would probably be on the root of your project. In your case this would be the `Layout.js` file.

```
const { publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
  [sepolia, polygonZkEvmTestnet, scrollTestnet, hardhat],
  [publicProvider()],
)
 
const config = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  publicClient,
  webSocketPublicClient,
})
```

Then specify the chain Id in your useContractRead Hook, as shown below.

```
    const {
        data: ownerAddress,
        isError,
        isLoading,
      } = useContractRead({
          address: RAFFLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
          abi: TOKENRAFFLE_CONTRACT_ABI,
          functionName: "owner", chainId: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly calling on a variable (owner) created in the constructor I would suggest adding a new function in your contract that retrieves the value behind the owner variable. A standard getOwner view function will do.

```
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
    return Owner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I think it is due to the fact that the blockchain state is outdated, some problem with the wagmi `publicClient` probably. I displayed the blockNumber and it shows me 3954448 even though currently the block number on sepolia is past 3981582.

Perhaps the fix is to use a custom provider that is reliable.

Comment: I used ```useBlockNumber``` to test if this could lead to diagnosing the issue and it seems to be on the current blockNumber in my case. I also tested my code again as is and it works now as expected. 

I think ultimately there was some external factor that was causing issues; maybe there was an issue with my WalletConnect project integration into the publicClient? I also didn't change any of my code within my WagmiProvider so not entirely sure why my code works now later in the week when it wasn't earlier in the week using the same code.

Comment: I changed for an Infura provider and it worked for me. Very probably that it was an external factor.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I resolved this by using the **enabled** flag set to false by default. This way it only gets called when function is called. In my opinion what happens is the Read/Write function gets called when the component is rendered. That's why it returns 0x000

```
export function useUsdtAllowance(address:any) {
    const { data: allowanceData } = useContractRead(  {
        address: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USDT_ADDRESS as `0x${string}`,
        abi: usdtABI,
        functionName: "allowance",
        args:[address,process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PIONEER_ADDRESS],
        enabled: false
      });
      return { allowanceData };
    };
```